# What is the proper api url for this method?

Tags: c#, webinvoke

I am consuming an api, the guy working in the backend uses c# and he could not explain to me the methods other than his code. But I don't have experience in c#. Can someone translate to me these lines and tell me what is the url part and what are the body params if any. Thanks!

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "UploadCat/{token}/{BID}/{CID}/{CAT}/{DATA}")]
        public HttpResponse UploadCat(string token, string BID, string CID, string CAT, List<CLMobileChangeDTO> DATA)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the encoding you could hit this API with curl like:

```
curl -X POST http://hostname/UploadCat/mytoken/myBID/myCID/myCAT/encodedDATA
```

The tricky part is how the framework you are using will encode a list of objects into URL safe characters to put it on the path. I don't think there is enough information in that code snippet to determine that.

Ideally you would use the post body to send List DATA instead of a path parameter.

Comment: Hi Ben thanks for your answer. Dou mean that is possible to send the params (myBID, myCID..) in the body as well as in the path?

Comment: Typically you would send a single object via the post body. Then you can use the path params to send each of those string parameters.